# example Rate limiting configuration of nginx in beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rate-limiting

I am trying to put rate limiting in nginx conf, I did the following in ./platform/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf file

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
    server {
        location / {
            limit_req zone=one;
            limit_req_dry_run on;
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the complete nginx.conf by creating a file
`.platform/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf` . It replaces the default nginx setup of BeanStalk.